# Connecting to Hive in R

Tags: r, hadoop, jdbc

I am trying to connect to hive in R. I have loaded RJDBC and rJava libraries on my R env.
I am using a Linux server with hadoop (hortonworks sandbox 2.1) and R (3.1.1) installed in the same box. This is the script I am using  to connect:

```
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default")
```

I get this error:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory

I have checked that my classpath contains all the jar files in `/usr/lib/hive` and `/usr/lib/hadoop`,but can not be sure if anything else is missing. Any idea what is causing the problem?? 
I am fairly new to R (and programming for that matter) so any specific steps are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I succesffuly connect to Hive from R just with RJDBC and a few configuration lines. I prefere RJDBC to rHive because rHive needs complex installations on all the node of the cluster (and I don't really understand why).

Here is my R solution :

```
#loading libraries
library("DBI")
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

#init of the classpath (works with hadoop 2.6 on CDH 5.4 installation)
cp = c("/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar", "/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-common.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-service.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar")
.jinit(classpath=cp)

#init of the connexion to Hive server
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar", identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/mydb", "myuser", "")

#working with the connexion
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
show_databases
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect to hiveserver2 from R using the RHIVE package

Below are the commands that I had to use.

```
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/usr/local/hive") Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop") rhive.env(ALL=TRUE) rhive.init() rhive.connect("localhost")
```